# Why do we make private fields instead of package local

Tags: java, scope

1. Is there any overhead when using default access level on class field in Java?
   I mean "any", even nanoseconds on startup.
   I heard JVM makes a graph of scopes for fields, that could be a possible reason for overhead.
2. I'm too lazy to write the private keyword. Is there any good reason to write private keyword instead of package-local? Package local seems to be local enough.

Answer (score 1):

"is there any good reason to write private"?

Yes there is a good reason. You do not want your private members to be accessed.

See this site for a summary of the access modifiers and when and why you should use them,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

- private = it is not okay for them to be changed other than the mother class.
- no modifier = it is okay for them to be changed by any class within the same package.
- protected = same as no modifier + it is okay to be changed by a subclass
- public = it is okay for them to be changed in general.

If you clicked the link above you would heed warning to their recommendation

> Use the most restrictive access level that makes sense for a
>   particular member. Use private unless you have a good reason not to.

If you put no modifier you are effectively saying,

"I explicitly want other programmers to change these fields if their class is in the same package as mine."

You should *always* put private unless otherwise and by doing this you are saying,

"I do not want other programmers to change these fields."

Answer (score 0):

You ask about elementary OOP knowledge
You see OOP has 4 basic principles

1. Inherritance
2. Abstraction
3. Polymorphism
4. **Encapsulation** -this is when `private` or `protected` keyword arrices on the scene

By these keywords you can restrict acces to certain fields of an object so they cant be "seen" from outside

And now for your question

**I'm too lazy to write the private keyword. Is there any good reason to write private keyword instead of package-local?**

Encapsulation helps the developer to make the code more flexible and maintainable .With well encapsulation implementation, one can change one part of the code easily without affecting the other part of the code.

Comment: Did you know actually package-local is more restricting than protected?